# GameLoop checking for input (Android/GlSurfaceView)

Tags: android, input, touch-event, glsurfaceview, game-loop

If I have some basic game loop in a thread, like this:

```
public void run(){
    getInput(); //onTouchEvent method is only available in view class.
    updateState();
    renderScreen();     
}
```

I was wondering how to actually check for input (touchscreen ie). I know I can use the onTouchEvent() in my view class, but I want to check it from my game loop. How is this done ?

ps: i'm using android with GlSurfaceView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually i would copy the input events in the UI thread and make them available to the game thread in a threadsafe fashion.

You may use the input implementation of libgdx as a good [example](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidInput.java).

Comment: The problem is that once the UI thread returns from onTouchEvent, the event you received may be overwritten with the next event. So to keep the data until your game is ready to use it you need to copy it.

Comment: That is completely up to you and the needs of your game. Create your own input event and copy the data from the original Android events.

Comment: So you mean like storing the MotionEvent as an variable, and using passing it to the gameloop ?

Comment: You can't store MotionEvent because of the reason mentioned above but you can store it's x and y values.